# Файл Activity не видет id объекта

Tags: android, recyclerview, activity

---

Я столкнулся с такой проблемой. Activity не видет id объекта. 
Вот MainActivity:

```java
package com.totrail.totrail;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.InflateException;
//import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.totrail.totrail.Adapter.FeedAdapter;
import com.totrail.totrail.Common.HTTPDataHandler;
import com.totrail.totrail.Model.RSSObject;



import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    Toolbar toolbar;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RSSObject rssObject;

    private final String RSS_link="https://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/Science.xml";
    private final String RSS_to_Json_API = " https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=";
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "voda_zahlebnulas-kolobok_povesilsa";
    public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_TOKEN = "token"; // User's API token
    public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_STARTED = "nonononono";
    public String token = "waiting...";
    SharedPreferences mSettings;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("News");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getBaseContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        loadRSS();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
//        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("7CF9814273473873DA112443352BE854")
                .build();
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
//        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
//        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        mSettings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(mSettings.contains(APP_PREFERENCES_STARTED)) {
            // TODO: make very cool welcome screen
        } else {
            // TODO: and here is too! :-)
        }
        if(mSettings.contains(APP_PREFERENCES_TOKEN)) {
            token = mSettings.getString(APP_PREFERENCES_TOKEN, "");
        } else {
            token = "not_login_in";
        }

    }

    private void loadRSS() {
        AsyncTask<String, String, String> loadRSSAsync = new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {

            ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                mDialog.setMessage("Ждите...");
                mDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String result;
                HTTPDataHandler http = new HTTPDataHandler();
                result = http.GetHTTPData(params[0]);
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
                rssObject = new Gson().fromJson(s, RSSObject.class);
                FeedAdapter adapter = new FeedAdapter(rssObject, getBaseContext());
                View.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        StringBuilder url_get_data = new StringBuilder(RSS_to_Json_API);
        url_get_data.append(RSS_link);
        loadRSSAsync.execute(url_get_data.toString());
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_refresh)
            loadRSS();
        return true;

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, loginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_tools) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

А вот xml:

```java
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/top_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="717dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            />



    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Собственно говоря не видет он recyclerView**

Comment: попробуйте перестроить проект, такое бывает временами

Comment: @Andrew То есть сделать ReBuild?

Comment: Да, либо перезагрузка с очисткой кэша, такие косяки не редкость))